# Mostrar resposta em pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, css

Vou cadastrar cpf dentro do código para não precisar de banco de dados quando o cpf digitado for autorizado deve mostrar a mensagem liberando a lista de acesso.

se o cpf não estiver autorizado deve aparecer a mensagem informando que o cpf não está autorizado.

Para fazer a varredura eu vou inserir os cpf dentro do código, não são muito, por isso não precisa de banco de dados

---

```html
<h1 class="page__title heading h1" style="text-align: center;">Acesso a lista</h1>
<p style="text-align: center;"><input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);"> 
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Enviar" onclick="doSomething();">
<script>// <![CDATA[
function searchKeyPress(e)
{
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function doSomething(){
  alert('Aqui vou colocar o endereço da lista para download',);
}
// ]]></script>
</p>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: CPF é um dado sensível, não se deixa isso no código.
Agora voltando para a sua questão, você não disse claramente no que você precisa de ajuda.